# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL for URL from camera roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsurl, photolibrary

I have some URLs for the videos stored in camera rolls. For example:

**file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0249.MP4**

I would like to further process those videos as NSData, but if I use

```
NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0249.MP4"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
```

The data is always nil. And I get the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_0249.MP4”
>   couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0249.MP4,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x165351d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
>   "Operation not permitted"}}

I noticed that if the URL is from my local app document folder, I can generate NSData without any issues. I wonder if it's not allowed to create NSData out of the videos stored in Camera Roll. I wonder if I need to use the Photos framework or some other method in order to have the permission.

Comment: Use `+dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error` and report the error in your Q.

Comment: `videoURL` is not `nil`. right?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad The url is not nil. I've updated the question based on your suggestions.

Comment: And the curtain lifted …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I can't turn a URL for Camera Rolls videos into NSData directly, I need to use PHImageManager to do that (And use the localIdentifier of the PHAsset of the video I acquired in the past):

```
PHFetchResult* assets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[videoID] options:nil];

PHAsset *asset = assets.firstObject;
if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeVideo) {
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
        if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
            AVURLAsset* urlAsset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlAsset.URL];
            [self sendToTwitter:data withMessage:message account: account];
        }
    }];
}
```

My guess is that the **AVURLAsset* urlAsset** has some additional permission info that my previous approach through **[NSURL fileURLWithPath]** doesn't have.